# Is it a problem that BufferBlock is always on?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core, logging, tpl-dataflow

I need log provider for my .NET Core project (especially, I want to send logs to Graylog with HTTP) and I searched all log repos on GitHub to find a good idea.

At the end of the day I found a few solutions and wanted to use the one that has `BufferBlock`;
But I have some questions.

Firstly, [here is the code](https://github.com/mattwcole/gelf-extensions-logging/blob/dev/src/Gelf.Extensions.Logging/GelfMessageProcessor.cs).

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;

namespace Gelf.Extensions.Logging
{
    public class GelfMessageProcessor
    {
        private readonly BufferBlock<GelfMessage> _messageBuffer;

        private Task _processorTask = Task.CompletedTask;

        public GelfMessageProcessor(IGelfClient gelfClient)
        {
            GelfClient = gelfClient;
            _messageBuffer = new BufferBlock<GelfMessage>(new DataflowBlockOptions
            {
                BoundedCapacity = 10000
            });
        }

        internal IGelfClient GelfClient { get; set; }

        public void Start()
        {
            _processorTask = Task.Run(StartAsync);
        }

        private async Task StartAsync()
        {
            while (!_messageBuffer.Completion.IsCompleted)
            {
                try
                {
                    var message = await _messageBuffer.ReceiveAsync();
                    await GelfClient.SendMessageAsync(message);
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException)
                {
                    // The source completed without providing data to receive.
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.Fail("Unhandled exception while sending GELF message.",
                        ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            _messageBuffer.Complete();
            _processorTask.Wait();
        }

        public void SendMessage(GelfMessage message)
        {
            if (!_messageBuffer.Post(message))
            {
                Debug.Fail("Failed to add GELF message to buffer.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you check this code, you can see that we have a `BufferBlock` where we have sent messages. And this block receive our message and send in a while loop, this while loop never stop in this project because it’s never been triggered as `IsCompleted`.

My first question is;

1. Its `BufferBlock` is looking always on, should I close this block?
2. Is it normal to being always on? If it stays on through the process, how much memory does it consume?
3. What would happen if no message came to `BufferBlock` for few hours?

I want to use this, but I’m confused for this two questions, I couldn't find any answer. I can't predict what kind of problems it will cause unless I find the answers.

Also, I am open to suggestions about how to send logs to Graylog with HTTP and without using `BufferBlock`, maybe we can find a different way. (Please don't suggest me NuGet packages, I have to do without packages.)

Comment: Why do you need a bufferblock? Why not send to GelfClient directly?

Comment: Have you considered replacing the `BufferBlock<GelfMessage>`+`Task StartAsync()` with a simpler `ActionBlock<GelfMessage>`? The [`ActionBlock<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1) block doesn't need to be started. It is already started upon creation.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias What will this solution exactly facilitate? I think, I can ask the same memory management questions from above for ActionBlock.

Comment: Using an `ActionBlock<T>` would be practically the same thing, just simpler, minus the ability to defer the starting of the consuming loop (in case you need this ability). My comment is just a side-note, not an answer to your question.

Comment: @Magnus I don't have to use BufferBlock. If you have a good opinion I want to try it. What is GelfClient? Do you mean send directly on http request?

Comment: Just call GelfClient.SendMessageAsync(message); directly instead of bufferblock?

Comment: @Magnus Oh now I get it, I dont know, maybe BufferBlock more effective than just sending with http. If I can get answers to my questions, I will understand. But if too many requests(logs) come in , I think httpPost can get deadlock, maybe we need BufferBlock in this case.

Comment: @dev the code you posted is trying to do the job of an `ActionBlock<>`. I suspect you read an article somewhere that the Dataflow library is a way of implementing agents in C#. It's not. It's a very [different programming paradigm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dataflow_programming), that's actually called `Dataflow`. What you tried to do can be done in a single line with ActionBlock, eg `var block=new ActionBlock<GelfMessage>(msg=>GelfClient.SendMessageAsync(msg);`. The rest is settings and a loop to post messages.

Comment: @dev in a dataflow you have processing blocks that process messages to each other along links. The TPL Dataflow library targets that scenario so there's no need to explicitly read/write to buffers, retrieve or post messages or handle tasks. That's why it has *none* of the features you'd expect in a higher-level agent library like Akka.NET or Proto.Actor